# Focus issue in gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a gridview in my layout. I have added three imageviews to this gridview.

I have the following requirement. By default when I launch or resume the activity, I need to have an imageview selected by default. How can I accomplish that? Placing **gridView.setSelection(1);** in **onResume()** have no effect ie; the imageview does not get selected on launching or resume, I wonder why! Can someone please let me know why this does not get highlighted?

Following is my main activity and adapter class.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
GridView gridView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    // set up the onClick listener
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Pos", "setOnItemClickListener() - pos:" + position);
            handleItemClick(position);
        }
    });

}
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gridView.setSelection(1);
}
private void handleItemClick(int position) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        switch(position) {
            case 0:  // Phone
                intent.setClassName("com.android.contacts",
                        "com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity");
                break;
            case 1:  // People
                intent.setClassName("com.android.contacts",
                        "com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity");
                intent.setAction("com.android.contacts.action.LIST_CONTACTS");
                break;
            case 2:  // Places
                intent.setClassName("com.android.contacts",
                        "com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in an array   
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.call, 
    R.drawable.contacts,
    R.drawable.music,
};

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView; 

    if (convertView == null) {           
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);  
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 350));  
    } else {  
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;   
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setId(position);

    return imageView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Thread.sleep(1);
    gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
    gridview.setSelection(1); 
}
```

or also this can help:

public void onResume() {

```
super.onResume();
mGridView.setSelection(1);
mGridView.requestFocusFromTouch();
mGridView.setSelection(1);
```

}

Comment: ok, this works. but the issue I noticed is when I press the return button immediately after pressing an imageview, ie; even before the next activity is launched, later when I come back from next activity I do not have the focus. So, my question is, in the above code, is there any method I can make the touch disabled for other areas in the screen except for the imageviews?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess may work

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridView.setSelection(1); <--- try to add this here
```